# Asking for help to refactor SQLite database design

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have two tables : products and tags.

### products

key | name | description | url

### tags

key2 | tag | tag description

### Association

- One tag can be associated with many products.
- each product has one or more tags associated with it.

eg a product "plate" has the tags "ceramic", "white", "delicate", etc associated with it.

I don't know however how to create a many-to-many representation.

What's the best way to store these tag associations? Create a tags field in products? Or another table? Thanks!

Edit: tags are many-to-many, thanks S.Lott

Comment: This isn't homework....I haven't taken a database class and I'm working on a project on the side.

Comment: In that case, please find a database design tutorial -- there are thousands online -- do the entire tutorial.  Really.  All of it.  Then revise your question based on that tutorial.  This is pretty easy stuff, well described in Wikipedia as well as thousands of database design tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with an additional table named (productTags: key, productKey, tagKey) that would map the two tables together.

Comment: Does this provide linear O(n) or constant O(1) time look-ups?

Comment: @oxuser: That depends on the index.  Not the table design.  Most SQL indexes are linear.

Comment: @S.Lott "Most SQL indexes are linear." that isn't right; the indexes are `O(log n)` if they are tree based or `O(1)` if hash based.

Answer (score 3):

> One tag can be associated with many products and each product has one or more tags associated with it.

That's not a one-to-many.  That's many-to-many.

Google "Association Table" or "Junction Table" for numerous examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_nhBKs25DQ